# Unterschied zwischen "denken" und "sich denken"

Tags: difference, usage

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen

> 1) "Ich denke mir, dass das der Fall ist." und "Ich denke, dass das der Fall ist."
>   2) "Das denke ich auch." und "Das dachte ich mir."

oder bedeuten die Sätze in den Fällen dasselbe?

Habe beides *denken* und *sich denken* ganz oft gehört, der Unterschied ist mir allerdings nicht so klar. Dazu eine Erklärung über die Verwendung der zwei wäre besser, damit ich diese nicht mehr verwechsle. Wenn ich mich nicht irre oder soweit ich verstehe, lassen sich *denken* und *sich denken* als *to think* übersetzen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich versuche mal, das zu erläutern. Ist aber nicht meine Stärke.

*Ich denke* kann heißen, dass Du an etwas oder jemanden denkst, einer bestimmten Meinung bist, oder etwas vermutest. Übersetzen würde man das mit *I think*.

z.B.

> Ich denke, dass München das Fußballspiel heute Abend gewinnt.
>
> *I think Munich will win tonight's football match.*
>
> Ich denke an meine Schwester.
>
> *I'm thinking of my sister*

*Ich denke mir* in all seinen Formen wird anders verwendet. Das würde man hauptsächlich verwenden, wenn man z.B. zum Ausdruck bringen möchte, dass man etwas nachvollziehen kann, etwas hat kommen sehen, oder selbst bereits zu einem bestimmten Schluss gekommen ist.

> A: Ich bin gestern einfach nicht von meiner Freundin weggekommen!
>
> *I didn't manage to get out of doing something with my girlfriend yesterday night.*
>
> B: Hab ich mir gedacht. Du hast dich ja auch den ganzen Abend nicht gemeldet.
>
> *I kinda **figured**, you didn't contact me for the entire evening*.
>
> A: Ich habe momentan viel Stress in der Uni.
>
> *I'm currently having a stressful time at the university*.
>
> B: Kann ich mir denken / Denke ich mir.
>
> *"**understandable**"* or *"**I can understand that**"*.

*Das denke ich auch* und seine Variationen kann man benutzen um auszudrücken, dass man mit jemandem einer Meinung ist und somit impliziert auch seiner Meinung zustimmt.

> A: Wir kommen da nie pünktlich hin!
>
> B: Das denke ich auch.
>
> A: Der würde uns doch nicht einfach sitzenlassen..
>
> B: Das denke ich auch nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied zwischen *denken* und *sich denken* ist in etwa wie *to think* und *to think to oneself*, also "sich im Stillen denken" oder "vermuten".

Wenn Du ausdrücken willst, dass Du einer Meinung ebenfalls bist, dann verwendest Du *Das denke ich auch*.

Wenn Du ausdrücken willst, dass jetzt etwas bestätigt wurde, was Du zwar vorher schon vermutet hattest oder Dir vorstellen konntest, aber noch nicht genau wusstest, dann verwendest Du *Das dachte ich mir* (*I thought so*).

Ein Beispiel dafür ist auch

> Genau *so* habe ich mir das gedacht (*This* is just how I intended it to be)

was im Sinne von

> Genau *so* hatte ich das geplant/mir vorgestellt/wollte ich es haben.

verwendet wird.

> Ich denke mir, dass das der Fall ist

drückt eine Vermutung aus oder dass man sich vorstellen kann, dass etwas der Fall ist. Äquivalent zu *Ich vermute/kann mir vorstellen, dass das der Fall ist*.

> Ich denke, dass das der Fall ist

drückt aus, dass *Deiner Meinung nach* etwas der Fall ist.

Answer (score 0):

**Sich denken** wird mit folgender Bedeutung verwendet:

> ein Bild od. eine Ahnung davon haben, wie jemand/etwas ist, sein könnte od. sein wird
>
> [Quelle](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/denken)

und entspricht demnach  ungefähr **sich etwas vorstellen**.

Demnach ist der Satz

> Ich denke mir, dass das der Fall ist

gleichbedeutend mit "Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass..." (in meinem Inneren).